# What's the fastest way to download large file via boost asio iostream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to download/transfer a large file via boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream like:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("127.0.0.1", "1234");
stream << "GET /data HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" << std::flush;
std::string text;
while (std::getline(stream, text)) {
    // pass, no operation here
}
```

However, the code takes more than 3s to download a 400MB file on my local machine which is too slow for a **localhost** file transfer. Can anyone give me any advise on how to speed it up?

Comment: the download speed is not a matter of your code, but of your internet connection.

Comment: Don't read line-by-line, read by blocks of some power-of-2, like 65536.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Can you explain more? The file server and my program is on the same machine, so I think the "internet connection" should be quite fast

Comment: For me not enough context. This line `std::getline(stream, text)` suggest text file possibly some xml. Issue can be hidden inside a loop.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, you can just assume it's a xml file. While doing the profiling, I actually do nothing in each iteration, so don't bother about what is inside the for loop.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, didnt read carefully enough

Answer (score 4):

If you really (?) want to /dev/null the data, here's a hack:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("127.0.0.1", "1234");
stream << "GET /data HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" << std::flush;
std::ostream ons(nullptr);
ons << stream.rdbuf();
```

If you really want to download the file, indeed, read until the headers:

```
for (std::string text; std::getline(stream, text);)
    if (text.empty())
        break; // end of headers
```

And then block-wise read for the body:

```
char buf[2048];
while (stream.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || stream.gcount()) {
    // do something with gcount() bytes in buf?
}
```

### ADVANCED HTTP AWARENESS

Of course, HTTP is a fickle beast. It can use compression, chunked encoding, keep-alive etc. This could easily lead to you reading a corrupt body. To be safer, use Beast to do your chores:

```
int main() {
    net::io_context io;
    tcp::socket s(io);
    s.connect({{}, 1234});

    std::string const& req = "GET /data HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    net::write(s, net::buffer(req));

    http::request<http::string_body> response;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    http::read(s, buf, response);
}
```

For even more awareness, why not compose/send the request in the same way:

```
{
    http::request<http::empty_body> req;
    req.method(http::verb::get);
    req.target("/data");
    req.version(10);
    http::write(s, req);
}
```

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66a8d438b7ff55ed)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using net::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    net::io_context io;
    tcp::socket s(io);
    s.connect({{}, 1234});

    {
        http::request<http::empty_body> req;
        req.method(http::verb::get);
        req.target("/data");
        req.version(10);
        http::write(s, req);
    }

    {
        http::request<http::string_body> response;
        beast::flat_buffer buf;
        http::read(s, buf, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I've tried the block-wise implementation with buffer size (4096, 40960, 65535) and can't get an obvious speed up compared to my original naive line-by-line implementation:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de4e8d4ae620b717

Comment: @konchy so, what are the timings? Perhaps there is no reason to expect a speed up

Comment: both of them(line-by-line & block-wise) take about 3 seconds for a 400MB file transfer in my test environment, I've tried libcurl then, and it takes less than 1 second.@sehe

Comment: I remember doing some benchmarks, let me see whether I saved them somewhere.

Comment: Mmm. I have found a benchmark which was focused on response latency: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3e61cda056123ae However when I run it with any significant body size (e.g. `./test 33554432 33554432` which means each response is ~32MiB) I can see bandwidth easily reach 4.25GiB (both ways, so 8+GiB/s) e..g using `iftop -i lo -f "tcp port 6767"`

Comment: When I up the response size to 320mib, the benchmark fails (probably due to allocation failure?) but I can see the transfer rate be 20-30GiB/s, which matches the [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php) limits on my system.

Comment: Can you try "boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream"? Tuning block-size can affect the transfer speed, but I don't think it's the reason why std::getline(line-by-line) method is slow in my test environment. Maybe there is some low level setting for "boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream"  that I don't know? @sehe